# How to extract exception in the test log in test complete

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am trying to get the exception description in the test log but its not giving the description.

```
catch(exception)
    {
        //Log.Error("Exception", VarToStr(exception.description));
        Log.Error("Exception", aqConvert.VarToStr(exception));
       
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to write the error details to Details tab of TestComplete log, you should call exception.message property to get the exception cause, or err.stack if you wish to see the whole call stack for easier debugging.

```
catch(exception){
    Log.Error("Exception", exception.message);
}
```